# Responsive web design - How to implement JavaScript part?

Tags: javascript, mobile, responsive-design, mobile-website

I'm preparing to make the web page responsive from a old existing complex one. https://www.lendingclub.com/browse/browse.action

I use media query for the CSS part, making different CSS work for different width of the browser. I want to ask:

- How do you deal with the JavaScript part, if some functions only exist in the mobile version (and narrow width browser on PC)?
- What I am doing is by the current window width:

> ```
>    window.onresize = function(){ if (document.body.clientWidth <= 720){……}}
> ```

Is it the best and primary way for the 'responsive js'?

We use YUI in old PC pages, do not include any mobile framework.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I use these values to implement responsive web design in Javascript:

```
screen.height;
screen.width;
```

Also, if some functions are not available in mobile, no script to be runned on mobile should call these functions.

Comment: yes, currently I use: window.onresize = function(){if(document.body.clientWidth <= 720){……}} I'm not sure if it's effective.

Comment: Misunderstood your question, sorry for that. I changed my answer to fit your question.